# Prometheus query check if value exist

Tags: prometheus, promql, victoriametrics

I have a query that gets a pipeline builds and its divided by the number of change request open in a 1 month window, which gives a percentage. Although, sometimes the values for project_id doesn't exist, but still end up showing up as one. I believe it's the logic that it's written, but is there any conditions that can be used if there's no data recieved it returns a 0.

```
(count((1, last_over_time(pipelin_builds{project_id="999", prod="yes", change!="none", section="builds", status="success"}[4w])))/count(change{change_project="dap"})) OR vector(1)
```

what I tried doing is putting a condition or an absent function,but not sure if thats the correct approach.

```
(count(absent(pipelin_builds{project_id="999"})(1, last_over_time(pipelin_builds{project_id="999", prod="yes", change!="none", section="builds", status="success"}[4w])))/count(change{change_project="dap"})) OR vector(1)
```